# setting ANT_OPTS in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ant

Does anyone know how to set ANT_OPTS in eclipse's ant runner and have it picked up?

I've tried setting it via the Environment tab in the External Tools setup, but that doesn't appear to be picked up.

I'm trying to set the following:

-Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties

so that I can turn on debug logging in some Oracle deployment ant tasks.  Their instructions specifically say to set ANT_OPTS, although any other way to get ant to pick up the setting would be fine as wel.

Comment: It looks like adding the "-Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties" to the JRE tab in the VM Arguments textbox solved the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct:
The kind of *JRE* property is to be set in the Argument tab (*VM* part) of a launcher:

[image]
<sub>(source: [sim-bio.org](http://www.sim-bio.org/javaspaces/quickstart/images/javaspaces/quickstart/RunArgumentsTab.png))</sub>

> The Environment tab defines the environment variable values to use when running or debugging a Java application. By default, the environment is inherited from the Eclipse runtime. You may override or append to the inherited environment.

[image]
<sub>(source: [eclipse.org](http://help.eclipse.org/help32/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tips/images/org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui/env_tab.png))</sub>